# Simple custom layer in keras, tensorflow confusion

Tags: tensorflow, keras, complex-numbers

First before I explain, here's the relevant code snippet:

```
input = Input(shape=(784, ))
hidden1 = Dense(784, activation='relu')(input)
hidden2 = Dense(784, activation='relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(1568, activation='relu')(hidden2)
hidden4 = Lambda(lambda x: makeComplex(x))(hidden3)
hidden5 = Reshape((1, 28, 28))(hidden4)
hidden6 = Lambda(lambda x: ifft2(x))(hidden5)
hidden7 = Flatten()(hidden6)
output = Dense(train_targets.shape[1], activation='linear')(hidden7)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
print(model.summary())
```

where ifft2(x) is

```
def ifft2(x):
    import tensorflow as tf
    return tf.cast(tf.spectral.ifft2d(tf.cast(x,dtype=tf.complex64)),tf.float32)
```

My goal now is to implement the makeComplex method.

Basically, it gets a vector of size 1568, and I want it to return a vector of size 784 in the following very simple fashion:

`new[k] = old[k] + old[k + 1] * i` where `i` is the imaginary unit

Here's my attempt:

```
def makeComplex(x):
    y = np.zeros((1, 784))
    for i in range(784):
        y[i] = np.complex(x[i], x[i + 1])
    return y
```

ofcourse this doesnt work because x is not actually a vector but rather a tensorflow tensor. Something I know nothing about. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

An example of tensor [1.,2.,3.,4.], what you want is [1.+2.j,3.+4.j]. I think you can use `tf.gather` to get two tensors `[1.,2.]` and `[3.,4.]`, then use `tf.complex` to get the answer.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.constant([1.,2.,3.,4.])
real = tf.gather(a,np.arange(0,a.get_shape().as_list()[0],2)) 
imag = tf.gather(a,np.arange(1,a.get_shape().as_list()[0],2))

res = tf.complex(real, imag)
```

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check it.